# Removing duplicates from dataframe with index + row matching

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `pandas` `DataFrame`s and I want to join them together such that I get the outer join with the duplicates removed.  My problem is that `.drop_duplicates()` ignores the index when finding duplicates.  If the index is different then it shouldn't be a duplicate.  How do I remove duplicates if the row index and columns are duplicates?  The only thing I can think of is using `df.to_dict()` and then create a new DataFrame (very inefficient).

**Update:**

As requested here is an example of my data:

```
from pandas import *
index1 = ['2012-05-2' + str(i) for i in range(0,6)]
data1 = {'rate': range(0,6)}
a = DataFrame(data1, index1)

index2 = ['2012-05-2' + str(i) for i in range(3,9)]
data2 = {'rate': range(3,9)}
b = DataFrame(data2, index2)
```

Glen

Comment: Have you checked if `a.combine_first(b)` is what you want? Otherwise can you give an example of your data and what you expect / want the result to be?

Comment: Have you tried with `pandas.merge(A, B, method="outer")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
a.combine_first(b)
```

Thanks Wes.